# Folder exist in C# but it's not work through my Code?

Tags: c#, firefox

I have read in forums that `%APPDATA%\Mozilla\` can be used to check folder. I just write a console app to test if c# can handle this.

```
bool exist = System.IO.Directory.Exists(@"%APPDATA%\Mozilla\");
```

I have run it and it's say that folder not exist (value = false). it's not true. When I copy paste it in explorer.exe and it's show me a folder.

Someone tell me how to run c# code to test it.

Comment: Go to explorer, navigate to `%APPDATA%` and see what path it takes you too. Use that in your program.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure %100 but from [`Directory.Exists` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.exists.aspx)

> **The path parameter is permitted to specify relative or absolute path
>   information.** Relative path information is interpreted as relative to
>   the current working directory.

Looks like you can't use *system variables* in this method. On my machine, `%APPDATA%` is equal to `C:\Users\Soner\AppData\Roaming`.

Take a look [`Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.expandenvironmentvariables.aspx) also.

Comment: so what is the best practice to Location like one I have posted in my OP.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the string to Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables before using it. It will expand %APPDATA% (and other environment variables) to its full path.

```
string fullPath = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"%APPDATA%\Mozilla\");
bool exists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(fullPath);
```